# How to stop Windows Explorer from automatically creating metadata/ID3 tags for .mp3 files

Tags: metadata, id3

I just recently updated my laptop PC to the Windows 10 Creator's Update (1703), and I have run into a problem. I often download music via YouTube converting using www.flvto.biz. I download these .mp3 files directly to my downloads folder.

Previously, before the update, the metadata/ID3 tags were always empty. For instance, the title, artist, album, and genre fields were always blank. I would then transfer these files to my music folder and update these fields manually with Windows Media Player. I only update title and artist fields as I do not care to sort my music with the others.

After the update, whenever I save a song to the downloads folder the song automatically has the metadata fields (title, artist, album, genre) filled in. This information that gets filled in is also mostly wrong.

Is there any way to prevent Windows Explorer from automatically filling in these fields?

Thanks!

Jake Stiebler